# Get gateways of all interfaces in C++ for Linux

Tags: c++, linux, routes, gateway

Using netstat or route, and probably several other commands it is fairly simple to retrieve the default gateway in the main routing table. (Although extracting it is still harder than I expected it to be) But I have not found any way of finding each gateway for each interface.

Specifically I have wlan0 and eth0 interfaces, and each have their own standard gateway. Is there anyway to extract them from somewhere. Preferably in C++, for Linux distributions. (Ubuntu 12.04 to be specific)

**EDIT:**

*Perhaps my terminology is not correct, so I will try to clarify :*

- If I have solely my wlan0 interface operational on my laptop (i.e. I disconnect the lan cable).
- I have a default gateway with IP *.*.108.1, and local IP of *.*.108.56.
- Now if I connect the ethernet cable, I get a default gateway of *.*.105.129 and a local IP of *.*.105.170. The subnet mask for both is 255.255.255.128.

I would like to use both by setting my routing tables accordingly.

Perhaps if I misunderstood the purpose of the gateway, then let me explain my main **goal**.

> *I would like to be able to specify that Wireless connection is used, instead of the ethernet cable, and vice versa.*

**EDIT2:**

These are the routing commands I use to redirect UDP packets from port 5555 to be sent over wlan

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o wlan0 -t mangle -p udp --sport 5555 -j MARK --set-mark 1
ip rule add fwmark 1 table 1
ip route add dev wlan0 default via *.*.108.1 table 1
```

For the last command I need to provide some gateway, which is what I am looking for.

Comment: Since when does Linux have per-interface default gateways? Could you show the output of `netstat -rn`?

Comment: @Barmar t does not have multiple default gateways. I am actually referring to some external routing device which has been assigned some address.

Comment: Still not sure what you're trying to get. Interfaces don't have gateways. Each route has an associated gateway and interface.

Comment: @Barmar, I changed edited my post. Perhaps it clarifies my question.

Comment: Are you asking how to find out what the default gateway would be for the ethernet interface *before* you connect it?

Comment: @Barmar No. I would like to know what the wlan0 default gateway would be after I connected the ethernet cable..:)

Comment: When the ethernet is connected, the new default gateway replaces the old one, and the old one is forgotten. It doesn't get reloaded until the ethernet is disconnected again.

Comment: @Barmar, so if I wanted to specify which interface to use for specific tasks, I could just use the same gateway? That doesn't make sense and isn't possible.

Comment: You don't generally specify interfaces. The IP stack matches the destination against the routing table, and uses the interface of the route.

Comment: @Barmar, I do understand that this isn't normal. That's why I ask it here, because I couldn't find it myself.

Comment: Are you trying to force something to go out the WLAN even though the default gateway points to the Ethernet?

Comment: @Barmar, yes. And I would like to be able to extend this to more interfaces, when they are available.

Comment: Now I'm at the same point. Got any answer?